# Implement ForEach Iterator in Powershell

Tags: powershell, class, foreach

I have created a custom class in PowerShell which I would like to be able to access via the `foreach` command.

In PHP, I can do this by using `implements iterator` in my class declaration and implementing some variables and functions.  Is there something similar in PowerShell?  How do I let my PowerShell class be accessed by `foreach`?

Note: I'm using PowerShell Core

Comment: Can you show a example of what you are wanting to happen? maybe there is a better way then what you are thinking of

Comment: You need to implement [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable) interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend some IEnumerable implementation like this:

```
class Test : System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]
{
    Test($items)
    {
        $items -split ';' |% { $this.Add($_) }
    }
}

$test = New-Object Test('a;1;x;y;z;2;3;4')

foreach ($item in $test)
{
    Write-Host $item
}
```

The result:

```
a
1
x
y
z
2
3
4
```